Can't upgrade Ubuntu because of unmet dependencies
I'm new to linux. I've been trying to upgrade ubuntu but everytime I do I get an error saying it has unmet dependecies. How do I fix this?
phoesston@Xubuntu:~$ sudo apt update
Hit:1 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-security InRelease
Hit:2 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble InRelease                      
Hit:3 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-updates InRelease              
Hit:4 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble-backports InRelease            
Hit:5 https://ppa.launchpadcontent.net/git-core/ppa/ubuntu noble InRelease     
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
52 packages can be upgraded. Run 'apt list --upgradable' to see them.
phoesston@Xubuntu:~$ sudo apt upgrade
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt --fix-broken install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 gdb : Depends: libpython3.10 (>= 3.10.0) but it is not installable
 hexchat-python3 : Depends: libpython3.10 (>= 3.10.0) but it is not installable
 libpeas-1.0-0 : Depends: libpython3.10 (>= 3.10.0) but it is not installable
 libpython3.12-stdlib : Depends: mime-support but it is not installable
 linux-headers-6.5.0-45-generic : Depends: linux-hwe-6.5-headers-6.5.0-45 but it is not installable
 postgresql-14 : Depends: libicu70 (>= 70.1-1~) but it is not installable
                 Depends: libldap-2.5-0 (>= 2.5.4) but it is not installable
 python3.12 : Depends: mime-support but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt --fix-broken install' with no packages (or specify a solution).



I see a mix of python 3.10 and 3.12 -- what kind of upgrade are you attempting? When upgrading from an older release, like 22.04 to 24.04, the recommendation is to disable third party repositories first, upgrade, then re-enable. If on a 24.04 system, do you have anything like a miniforge3 environment with python3.10 installed?

The python3 version for Ubuntu 24.04 is Python 3.12 (not 3.10). That libraries want the older version is a strong indicator that your release-upgrade from 22.04 to 24.04 failed. Why, as a "new to linux" user, were you release-upgrading?

My guess is this is a self-created issue. You don't actually specify you release but I see noble (24.04), and like others I see many packages intended for jammy or 22.04 which would create package dependency issues if used on 24.04 as they weren't packaged for that release.  It maybe helpful if you're specific as to what you installed as details don't show a single release.

This question is similar to: How do I resolve unmet dependencies after adding a PPA?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
